# Overriding target in jQuery event

Tags: jquery, oop, events

Is it possible to override jQuerys `target` in a custom event?

f.ex:

```
var scope = function() {
    this.param = 'foo';
}

var instance = new scope();

$(instance).bind('bar', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});

$(instance).trigger('bar');
```

This outputs the entire instance object, as it should.

But if I want target to be something else, like `param` I can try:

```
var scope = function() {
    this.param = 'foo';
}

var instance = new scope();

$(instance).bind('bar', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.customTarget);
});

$(instance).trigger({
    type: 'bar',
    target: instance.param, // override  attempt
    customTarget: instance.param
});
```

This outputs **customTarget** as 'foo', but **target** remains the same.

I need to override target, but it seems impossible? I also tried doing so via the `jQuery.Event` with no luck.

Anyone?

Comment: Hold on, jQuery's custom event system is for binding/triggering events on *DOM nodes*, not your own `new scope()` object. 2ndly, no you can't change `target`. It's hardcoded to be set to the *node* you're triggering the event on.

Comment: Why not? The events works the same way on any object.

Comment: @David: I'm just telling you they're meant to work only DOM elements: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger  Yes you can fake it as you've shown, but this isn't documented nor well-defined. It may break in future versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just pass customTarget and re-assign target in the called eventhandler?

```
var scope = function() {
    this.param = 'foo';
}

var instance = new scope();

$(instance).bind('bar', function(e) {
    e.target = e.customTarget;
    // do stuff
});

$(instance).trigger({
    type: 'bar',
    customTarget: instance.param
});
```